# Minecraft Forge - Block dissappear when placed by setBlockState

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I started with coding mods recenlty, I can code in java so I understand lots of stuff. But there is on thing, that I can not figure out, and that is, why this command doesnt work?

```
Minecraft.getMinecraft().world.setBlockState(new BlockPos(10,65,1140),Blocks.BEDROCK.getDefaultState(), 2);
```

Actually it works, but when I right click this block, it dissappears and I dont know what to do next, when I relog it dissappears so probably it is not rendered properly. Can anyone tell me how to fix that?

I am using Minecraft 1.12 version.

Answer (score 2):

You've tried to alter the world (a sever variable) by altering the client's copy of the data (a...client variable).

You need to perform your change on the server.

How do you get access to the server world? Entirely depends on where your line of code is running...